# My SVGs are not loading consistently

Tags: css, svg, transition, fill

For some reason when using inline SVGs they do not load consistently. When I reload the page, intermittently they might only load "Pay" or "Pay" with just the shadow for "Pal".

Ideally I can load them externally for caching, however I also haven't been able to transition their fill color when loading externally.

I have included a fiddle below, but unfortunately I haven't been able to reproduce the issue of them loading intermittently on JSFiddle :(

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6019/

```css
body {
  background-color: #efefef;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
#main {
  padding: 20px 0 265px 0;
}
button:hover .paypal_svg,
button:focus .paypal_svg {
  fill: #00cc00;
}
.purchase .paypal_svg {
  transition: fill 0.2s ease-in;
}
.purchase {
  background-color: #00cc00;
  border: 1px solid #00cc00;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
  padding: 10px;
}
.purchase:hover {
  background-color: #efefef;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  color: #00cc00;
  border: 1px solid #00cc00;
}
svg {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.tour {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
/* TEMP */

.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
.img-blue {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #336699;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Main Content -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container force-width">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ligula felis, rhoncus ac posuere id, dictum non augue. Sed commodo suscipit ex, at tempor ligula fringilla non.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 center">
          <div class="row">
            <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
              <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
              <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="P22AKP9VXVBSC">
              <button name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg purchase" type="submit">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <b>Buy <i>with</i></b>
                  <svg width="80" height="25" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                    <g>
                      <title>Layer 1</title>
                      <use x="0" xlink:href="#svg_74" id="svg_75" transform="matrix(1.2013322292349216,0,0,1.2013322292349216,1.222910267255557,0.24458211358629356) " y="0.825" />
                    </g>
                    <defs>
                      <svg id="svg_74" x="0px" y="0px" width="66px" height="19px" viewBox="0 0 66 19" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                        <g id="svg_76">
                          <g id="svg_77">
                            <path id="svg_78" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#999" d="m19,5c-1.5,0 -2.799999,0.4 -3.7,0.6l-0.3,2.4c0.4,-0.2 1.9,-0.6 3.1,-0.7c1.199999,0 1.9,0.2 1.699999,1.3c-3.599998,0 -6.099999,0.799999 -6.599999,3.099999c-0.7,4.1 3.7,4 5.400001,2.2l-0.200001,1h3.300001l1.4,-6.5c0.6,-2.8 -1.9,-3.5 -4.1,-3.4l0,0l0,0l0,0zm0.200001,6.6c-0.200001,0.9 -0.900002,1.2 -1.700001,1.299999c-0.700001,0 -1.299999,-0.599999 -0.9,-1.4c0.4,-0.6 1.4,-0.8 1.9,-0.8c0.299999,0 0.5,0 0.799999,0c0,0.400001 -0.099998,0.6 -0.099998,0.900001zm5.4,-6.400001h3.299999l0.5,5.8l3.200001,-5.8h3.4l-7.799999,13.8h-3.700001l2.4,-4.1l-1.299999,-9.7l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0zm-13.8,-2.8h-6.1l-2.7,12.5h3.6l0.9,-4.099999h2.5c2.5,0 4.5,-1.5 5,-4.1c0.7,-2.9 -1.4,-4.3 -3.2,-4.3l0,0l0,0l0,0zm-0.1,4.3c-0.2,0.9 -1.099999,1.7 -2,1.7h-1.7l0.7,-3.4h1.8c0.9,0 1.5,0.7 1.2,1.7z"
                            />
                          </g>
                          <g id="svg_79">
                            <path id="svg_80" class="paypal_svg" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#f5f5f5" d="m19,4c-1.5,0 -2.799999,0.4 -3.7,0.6l-0.3,2.4c0.4,-0.2 1.9,-0.6 3.1,-0.7c1.199999,0 1.9,0.2 1.699999,1.3c-3.599998,0 -6.099999,0.8 -6.599999,3.1c-0.7,4.1 3.7,4 5.400001,2.2l-0.200001,1h3.300001l1.4,-6.5c0.6,-2.8 -1.9,-3.5 -4.1,-3.4l0,0l0,0l0,0zm0.200001,6.6c-0.200001,0.9 -0.900002,1.2 -1.700001,1.299999c-0.700001,0 -1.299999,-0.599999 -0.9,-1.4c0.4,-0.6 1.4,-0.7 2,-0.7c0.299999,0 0.5,0 0.799999,0c-0.1,0.3 -0.199999,0.5 -0.199999,0.8l0,0l0,0l0,0zm5.4,-6.400001h3.299999l0.5,5.8l3.200001,-5.8h3.4l-7.799999,13.8h-3.700001l2.4,-4.1l-1.299999,-9.7l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0zm-13.8,-2.8h-6.1l-2.7,12.5h3.6l0.9,-4.099999h2.5c2.5,0 4.5,-1.5 5,-4.1c0.7,-2.9 -1.4,-4.3 -3.2,-4.3l0,0l0,0l0,0zm-0.1,4.3c-0.2,0.9 -1.099999,1.7 -2,1.7h-1.7l0.7,-3.4h1.8c0.9,0 1.5,0.7 1.2,1.7z"
                            />
                          </g>
                        </g>
                        <g id="svg_81">
                          <g id="svg_82">
                            <path id="svg_83" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#999" d="m50.900002,5c-1.600002,0 -2.800003,0.4 -3.700001,0.6l-0.400002,2.4c0.5,-0.2 2,-0.6 3.200001,-0.7c1.200001,0 2,0.2 1.700001,1.3c-3.700001,0 -6.200001,0.799999 -6.700001,3.099999c-0.700001,4.1 3.799999,4 5.5,2.2l-0.200001,1h3.299999l1.400002,-6.5c0.700001,-2.8 -1.799999,-3.5 -4.099998,-3.4l0,0l0,0l0,0zm0.199997,6.6c-0.199997,0.9 -0.899998,1.2 -1.699997,1.299999c-0.700001,0 -1.400002,-0.599999 -0.900002,-1.4c0.400002,-0.6 1.400002,-0.8 2,-0.8c0.299999,0 0.5,0 0.799999,0c-0.099998,0.400001 -0.099998,0.6 -0.200001,0.900001zm6.800003,-9.2l0,0h3.399998l-2.700001,12.5h-3.299999l2.600002,-12.5l0,0zm-15.300003,0h-6.099998l-2.700001,12.4h3.5l0.900002,-4.1h2.5c2.5,0 4.5,-1.5 5.099998,-4.1c0.700001,-2.8 -1.399998,-4.2 -3.200001,-4.2zm-0.099998,4.3c-0.200001,0.9 -1.200001,1.7 -2.099998,1.7h-1.600002l0.700001,-3.4h1.799999c0.900002,0 1.400002,0.7 1.200001,1.7zm19.5,-2.7v-1.5h-0.5v-0.2h1.299999v0.2h-0.599998v1.5h-0.200001l0,0zm1,0v-1.7h0.299999l0.400002,1.2c0,0.1 0.099998,0.2 0.099998,0.2c0,-0.1 0,-0.1 0.100002,-0.3l0.400002,-1.2h0.299995v1.8h-0.199997v-1.4l-0.5,1.4h-0.200001l-0.5,-1.4v1.4h-0.200001l0,0z"
                            />
                          </g>
                          <g id="svg_84">
                            <path id="svg_85" class="paypal_svg" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#f5f5f5" d="m50.900002,4c-1.600002,0 -2.800003,0.4 -3.700001,0.6l-0.400002,2.4c0.5,-0.2 2,-0.6 3.200001,-0.7c1.200001,0 2,0.2 1.700001,1.3c-3.700001,0 -6.200001,0.8 -6.700001,3.1c-0.700001,4.1 3.799999,4 5.5,2.2l-0.200001,1h3.299999l1.400002,-6.5c0.700001,-2.8 -1.799999,-3.5 -4.099998,-3.4zm0.199997,6.6c-0.199997,0.9 -0.899998,1.2 -1.699997,1.299999c-0.700001,0 -1.400002,-0.599999 -0.900002,-1.4c0.400002,-0.6 1.400002,-0.8 2,-0.8c0.299999,0 0.5,0 0.799999,0c-0.099998,0.400001 -0.099998,0.6 -0.200001,0.900001l0,0zm6.800003,-9.2l0,0h3.399998l-2.700001,12.5h-3.299999l2.600002,-12.5l0,0zm-15.300003,0h-6.099998l-2.700001,12.4h3.5l0.900002,-4.1h2.5c2.5,0 4.5,-1.5 5.099998,-4.1c0.700001,-2.8 -1.399998,-4.2 -3.200001,-4.2zm-0.099998,4.3c-0.200001,0.9 -1.200001,1.7 -2.099998,1.7h-1.600002l0.700001,-3.4h1.799999c0.900002,0 1.400002,0.7 1.200001,1.7zm19.5,-2.7v-1.5h-0.5v-0.2h1.299999v0.2h-0.599998v1.5h-0.200001l0,0zm1,0v-1.7h0.299999l0.400002,1.2c0,0.1 0.099998,0.2 0.099998,0.2c0,-0.1 0,-0.1 0.100002,-0.3l0.400002,-1.2h0.299995v1.8h-0.199997v-1.4l-0.5,1.4h-0.200001l-0.5,-1.4v1.4h-0.200001l0,0z"
                            />
                          </g>
                        </g>
                      </svg>
                    </defs>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </button>
              <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container force-width">
        <div class="col-md-12 tour">
          <div class="img-blue right"></div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi dignissim ante vitae auctor faucibus. Nunc est lorem, egestas a rutrum in, mollis nec nulla. Duis sit amet est vulputate, porta libero non, pellentesque elit. Aenean condimentum
            auctor posuere. Donec ut suscipit velit. Mauris sit amet aliquam augue. Mauris eleifend felis vitae consectetur varius. Donec eget mollis elit. Vestibulum nisl ante, lobortis a maximus tristique, bibendum sit amet enim. Nullam consectetur
            nec enim a sagittis. Nam eu finibus sapien. Aenean commodo turpis eu mauris bibendum, ut bibendum turpis ornare. Pellentesque tempus hendrerit sapien, vel finibus tellus placerat ut. Proin nisi nisi, vestibulum ut sodales eget, vehicula et
            mi. Vestibulum vel placerat tellus, at porttitor velit. Etiam et ornare urna, et hendrerit augue.</p>

          <p>Suspendisse congue facilisis augue et lacinia. Nulla convallis quam massa. Curabitur condimentum arcu at ante posuere pellentesque. Aliquam commodo, leo viverra sodales condimentum, ligula velit varius nunc, sit amet elementum justo tortor vitae
            arcu. Nam iaculis euismod malesuada. Quisque suscipit leo auctor, suscipit dui ac, viverra nisi. Donec sagittis tincidunt mi quis fermentum. Vivamus velit dolor, mollis in faucibus eget, tincidunt quis libero. Sed hendrerit, enim et venenatis
            faucibus, orci leo blandit sem, nec sagittis nunc sapien sit amet enim. Nam vel lorem in turpis imperdiet pharetra. Aenean ornare dictum neque, at faucibus enim faucibus et. Curabitur mauris nunc, commodo sed lectus sed, sodales bibendum nulla.
            Nullam non dolor accumsan, pulvinar massa quis, viverra dolor.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container force-width">
        <div class="col-md-12 tour">
          <div class="img-blue left"></div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi dignissim ante vitae auctor faucibus. Nunc est lorem, egestas a rutrum in, mollis nec nulla. Duis sit amet est vulputate, porta libero non, pellentesque elit. Aenean condimentum
            auctor posuere. Donec ut suscipit velit. Mauris sit amet aliquam augue. Mauris eleifend felis vitae consectetur varius. Donec eget mollis elit. Vestibulum nisl ante, lobortis a maximus tristique, bibendum sit amet enim. Nullam consectetur
            nec enim a sagittis. Nam eu finibus sapien. Aenean commodo turpis eu mauris bibendum, ut bibendum turpis ornare. Pellentesque tempus hendrerit sapien, vel finibus tellus placerat ut. Proin nisi nisi, vestibulum ut sodales eget, vehicula et
            mi. Vestibulum vel placerat tellus, at porttitor velit. Etiam et ornare urna, et hendrerit augue.</p>

          <p>Suspendisse congue facilisis augue et lacinia. Nulla convallis quam massa. Curabitur condimentum arcu at ante posuere pellentesque. Aliquam commodo, leo viverra sodales condimentum, ligula velit varius nunc, sit amet elementum justo tortor vitae
            arcu. Nam iaculis euismod malesuada. Quisque suscipit leo auctor, suscipit dui ac, viverra nisi. Donec sagittis tincidunt mi quis fermentum. Vivamus velit dolor, mollis in faucibus eget, tincidunt quis libero. Sed hendrerit, enim et venenatis
            faucibus, orci leo blandit sem, nec sagittis nunc sapien sit amet enim. Nam vel lorem in turpis imperdiet pharetra. Aenean ornare dictum neque, at faucibus enim faucibus et. Curabitur mauris nunc, commodo sed lectus sed, sodales bibendum nulla.
            Nullam non dolor accumsan, pulvinar massa quis, viverra dolor.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container force-width">
        <div class="col-md-12 tour">
          <div class="img-blue right"></div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi dignissim ante vitae auctor faucibus. Nunc est lorem, egestas a rutrum in, mollis nec nulla. Duis sit amet est vulputate, porta libero non, pellentesque elit. Aenean condimentum
            auctor posuere. Donec ut suscipit velit. Mauris sit amet aliquam augue. Mauris eleifend felis vitae consectetur varius. Donec eget mollis elit. Vestibulum nisl ante, lobortis a maximus tristique, bibendum sit amet enim. Nullam consectetur
            nec enim a sagittis. Nam eu finibus sapien. Aenean commodo turpis eu mauris bibendum, ut bibendum turpis ornare. Pellentesque tempus hendrerit sapien, vel finibus tellus placerat ut. Proin nisi nisi, vestibulum ut sodales eget, vehicula et
            mi. Vestibulum vel placerat tellus, at porttitor velit. Etiam et ornare urna, et hendrerit augue.</p>

          <p>Suspendisse congue facilisis augue et lacinia. Nulla convallis quam massa. Curabitur condimentum arcu at ante posuere pellentesque. Aliquam commodo, leo viverra sodales condimentum, ligula velit varius nunc, sit amet elementum justo tortor vitae
            arcu. Nam iaculis euismod malesuada. Quisque suscipit leo auctor, suscipit dui ac, viverra nisi. Donec sagittis tincidunt mi quis fermentum. Vivamus velit dolor, mollis in faucibus eget, tincidunt quis libero. Sed hendrerit, enim et venenatis
            faucibus, orci leo blandit sem, nec sagittis nunc sapien sit amet enim. Nam vel lorem in turpis imperdiet pharetra. Aenean ornare dictum neque, at faucibus enim faucibus et. Curabitur mauris nunc, commodo sed lectus sed, sodales bibendum nulla.
            Nullam non dolor accumsan, pulvinar massa quis, viverra dolor.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container force-width">
        <div class="col-md-12 center">
          <div class="row">
            <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
              <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
              <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="P22AKP9VXVBSC">
              <button name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg purchase" type="submit">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <b>Buy <i>with</i></b>
                  <svg width="80" height="25" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                    <g>
                      <title>Layer 1</title>
                      <use x="0" xlink:href="#svg_86" id="svg_87" transform="matrix(1.2013322292349216,0,0,1.2013322292349216,1.222910267255557,0.24458211358629356) " y="0.825" />
                    </g>
                    <defs>
                      <svg id="svg_86" x="0px" y="0px" width="66px" height="19px" viewBox="0 0 66 19" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                        <g id="svg_88">
                          <g id="svg_89">
                            <path id="svg_90" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#999" d="m19,5c-1.5,0 -2.799999,0.4 -3.7,0.6l-0.3,2.4c0.4,-0.2 1.9,-0.6 3.1,-0.7c1.199999,0 1.9,0.2 1.699999,1.3c-3.599998,0 -6.099999,0.799999 -6.599999,3.099999c-0.7,4.1 3.7,4 5.400001,2.2l-0.200001,1h3.300001l1.4,-6.5c0.6,-2.8 -1.9,-3.5 -4.1,-3.4l0,0l0,0l0,0zm0.200001,6.6c-0.200001,0.9 -0.900002,1.2 -1.700001,1.299999c-0.700001,0 -1.299999,-0.599999 -0.9,-1.4c0.4,-0.6 1.4,-0.8 1.9,-0.8c0.299999,0 0.5,0 0.799999,0c0,0.400001 -0.099998,0.6 -0.099998,0.900001zm5.4,-6.400001h3.299999l0.5,5.8l3.200001,-5.8h3.4l-7.799999,13.8h-3.700001l2.4,-4.1l-1.299999,-9.7l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0zm-13.8,-2.8h-6.1l-2.7,12.5h3.6l0.9,-4.099999h2.5c2.5,0 4.5,-1.5 5,-4.1c0.7,-2.9 -1.4,-4.3 -3.2,-4.3l0,0l0,0l0,0zm-0.1,4.3c-0.2,0.9 -1.099999,1.7 -2,1.7h-1.7l0.7,-3.4h1.8c0.9,0 1.5,0.7 1.2,1.7z"
                            />
                          </g>
                          <g id="svg_91">
                            <path id="svg_92" class="paypal_svg" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#f5f5f5" d="m19,4c-1.5,0 -2.799999,0.4 -3.7,0.6l-0.3,2.4c0.4,-0.2 1.9,-0.6 3.1,-0.7c1.199999,0 1.9,0.2 1.699999,1.3c-3.599998,0 -6.099999,0.8 -6.599999,3.1c-0.7,4.1 3.7,4 5.400001,2.2l-0.200001,1h3.300001l1.4,-6.5c0.6,-2.8 -1.9,-3.5 -4.1,-3.4l0,0l0,0l0,0zm0.200001,6.6c-0.200001,0.9 -0.900002,1.2 -1.700001,1.299999c-0.700001,0 -1.299999,-0.599999 -0.9,-1.4c0.4,-0.6 1.4,-0.7 2,-0.7c0.299999,0 0.5,0 0.799999,0c-0.1,0.3 -0.199999,0.5 -0.199999,0.8l0,0l0,0l0,0zm5.4,-6.400001h3.299999l0.5,5.8l3.200001,-5.8h3.4l-7.799999,13.8h-3.700001l2.4,-4.1l-1.299999,-9.7l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0zm-13.8,-2.8h-6.1l-2.7,12.5h3.6l0.9,-4.099999h2.5c2.5,0 4.5,-1.5 5,-4.1c0.7,-2.9 -1.4,-4.3 -3.2,-4.3l0,0l0,0l0,0zm-0.1,4.3c-0.2,0.9 -1.099999,1.7 -2,1.7h-1.7l0.7,-3.4h1.8c0.9,0 1.5,0.7 1.2,1.7z"
                            />
                          </g>
                        </g>
                        <g id="svg_93">
                          <g id="svg_94">
                            <path id="svg_95" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#999" d="m50.900002,5c-1.600002,0 -2.800003,0.4 -3.700001,0.6l-0.400002,2.4c0.5,-0.2 2,-0.6 3.200001,-0.7c1.200001,0 2,0.2 1.700001,1.3c-3.700001,0 -6.200001,0.799999 -6.700001,3.099999c-0.700001,4.1 3.799999,4 5.5,2.2l-0.200001,1h3.299999l1.400002,-6.5c0.700001,-2.8 -1.799999,-3.5 -4.099998,-3.4l0,0l0,0l0,0zm0.199997,6.6c-0.199997,0.9 -0.899998,1.2 -1.699997,1.299999c-0.700001,0 -1.400002,-0.599999 -0.900002,-1.4c0.400002,-0.6 1.400002,-0.8 2,-0.8c0.299999,0 0.5,0 0.799999,0c-0.099998,0.400001 -0.099998,0.6 -0.200001,0.900001zm6.800003,-9.2l0,0h3.399998l-2.700001,12.5h-3.299999l2.600002,-12.5l0,0zm-15.300003,0h-6.099998l-2.700001,12.4h3.5l0.900002,-4.1h2.5c2.5,0 4.5,-1.5 5.099998,-4.1c0.700001,-2.8 -1.399998,-4.2 -3.200001,-4.2zm-0.099998,4.3c-0.200001,0.9 -1.200001,1.7 -2.099998,1.7h-1.600002l0.700001,-3.4h1.799999c0.900002,0 1.400002,0.7 1.200001,1.7zm19.5,-2.7v-1.5h-0.5v-0.2h1.299999v0.2h-0.599998v1.5h-0.200001l0,0zm1,0v-1.7h0.299999l0.400002,1.2c0,0.1 0.099998,0.2 0.099998,0.2c0,-0.1 0,-0.1 0.100002,-0.3l0.400002,-1.2h0.299995v1.8h-0.199997v-1.4l-0.5,1.4h-0.200001l-0.5,-1.4v1.4h-0.200001l0,0z"
                            />
                          </g>
                          <g id="svg_96">
                            <path id="svg_97" class="paypal_svg" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#f5f5f5" d="m50.900002,4c-1.600002,0 -2.800003,0.4 -3.700001,0.6l-0.400002,2.4c0.5,-0.2 2,-0.6 3.200001,-0.7c1.200001,0 2,0.2 1.700001,1.3c-3.700001,0 -6.200001,0.8 -6.700001,3.1c-0.700001,4.1 3.799999,4 5.5,2.2l-0.200001,1h3.299999l1.400002,-6.5c0.700001,-2.8 -1.799999,-3.5 -4.099998,-3.4zm0.199997,6.6c-0.199997,0.9 -0.899998,1.2 -1.699997,1.299999c-0.700001,0 -1.400002,-0.599999 -0.900002,-1.4c0.400002,-0.6 1.400002,-0.8 2,-0.8c0.299999,0 0.5,0 0.799999,0c-0.099998,0.400001 -0.099998,0.6 -0.200001,0.900001l0,0zm6.800003,-9.2l0,0h3.399998l-2.700001,12.5h-3.299999l2.600002,-12.5l0,0zm-15.300003,0h-6.099998l-2.700001,12.4h3.5l0.900002,-4.1h2.5c2.5,0 4.5,-1.5 5.099998,-4.1c0.700001,-2.8 -1.399998,-4.2 -3.200001,-4.2zm-0.099998,4.3c-0.200001,0.9 -1.200001,1.7 -2.099998,1.7h-1.600002l0.700001,-3.4h1.799999c0.900002,0 1.400002,0.7 1.200001,1.7zm19.5,-2.7v-1.5h-0.5v-0.2h1.299999v0.2h-0.599998v1.5h-0.200001l0,0zm1,0v-1.7h0.299999l0.400002,1.2c0,0.1 0.099998,0.2 0.099998,0.2c0,-0.1 0,-0.1 0.100002,-0.3l0.400002,-1.2h0.299995v1.8h-0.199997v-1.4l-0.5,1.4h-0.200001l-0.5,-1.4v1.4h-0.200001l0,0z"
                            />
                          </g>
                        </g>
                      </svg>
                    </defs>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </button>
              <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The fiddle is in my post, https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6019/ it required I also include the code to post.

Comment: Thanks hjpotter92. I didn't know how to add that functionality! If you run the code snippet several times, eventually the SVG won't load. I am curious why that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be caused by some weird bug triggered by the slightly unusual way you are using `<use>`.

If you remove that and just have a simpler SVG in your button it seems to behave better.  After my changes I wasn't able to reproduce the disappearing logo fault.

(Testing on Chrome)

```css
body {
  background-color: #efefef;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
#main {
  padding: 20px 0 265px 0;
}
button:hover .paypal_svg,
button:focus .paypal_svg {
  fill: #00cc00;
}
.purchase .paypal_svg {
  transition: fill 0.2s ease-in;
}
.purchase {
  background-color: #00cc00;
  border: 1px solid #00cc00;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
  padding: 10px;
}
.purchase:hover {
  background-color: #efefef;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
  color: #00cc00;
  border: 1px solid #00cc00;
}
svg {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.tour {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
/* TEMP */

.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
.img-blue {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #336699;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Main Content -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container force-width">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ligula felis, rhoncus ac posuere id, dictum non augue. Sed commodo suscipit ex, at tempor ligula fringilla non.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 center">
          <div class="row">
            <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
              <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
              <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="P22AKP9VXVBSC">
              <button name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg purchase" type="submit">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <b>Buy <i>with</i></b>
                      <svg id="svg_74" width="80px" height="25px" viewBox="0 0 66 19" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                        <g id="svg_76">
                          <g id="svg_77">
                            <path id="svg_78" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#999" d="m19,5c-1.5,0 -2.799999,0.4 -3.7,0.6l-0.3,2.4c0.4,-0.2 1.9,-0.6 3.1,-0.7c1.199999,0 1.9,0.2 1.699999,1.3c-3.599998,0 -6.099999,0.799999 -6.599999,3.099999c-0.7,4.1 3.7,4 5.400001,2.2l-0.200001,1h3.300001l1.4,-6.5c0.6,-2.8 -1.9,-3.5 -4.1,-3.4l0,0l0,0l0,0zm0.200001,6.6c-0.200001,0.9 -0.900002,1.2 -1.700001,1.299999c-0.700001,0 -1.299999,-0.599999 -0.9,-1.4c0.4,-0.6 1.4,-0.8 1.9,-0.8c0.299999,0 0.5,0 0.799999,0c0,0.400001 -0.099998,0.6 -0.099998,0.900001zm5.4,-6.400001h3.299999l0.5,5.8l3.200001,-5.8h3.4l-7.799999,13.8h-3.700001l2.4,-4.1l-1.299999,-9.7l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0zm-13.8,-2.8h-6.1l-2.7,12.5h3.6l0.9,-4.099999h2.5c2.5,0 4.5,-1.5 5,-4.1c0.7,-2.9 -1.4,-4.3 -3.2,-4.3l0,0l0,0l0,0zm-0.1,4.3c-0.2,0.9 -1.099999,1.7 -2,1.7h-1.7l0.7,-3.4h1.8c0.9,0 1.5,0.7 1.2,1.7z"
                            />
                          </g>
                          <g id="svg_79">
                            <path id="svg_80" class="paypal_svg" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#f5f5f5" d="m19,4c-1.5,0 -2.799999,0.4 -3.7,0.6l-0.3,2.4c0.4,-0.2 1.9,-0.6 3.1,-0.7c1.199999,0 1.9,0.2 1.699999,1.3c-3.599998,0 -6.099999,0.8 -6.599999,3.1c-0.7,4.1 3.7,4 5.400001,2.2l-0.200001,1h3.300001l1.4,-6.5c0.6,-2.8 -1.9,-3.5 -4.1,-3.4l0,0l0,0l0,0zm0.200001,6.6c-0.200001,0.9 -0.900002,1.2 -1.700001,1.299999c-0.700001,0 -1.299999,-0.599999 -0.9,-1.4c0.4,-0.6 1.4,-0.7 2,-0.7c0.299999,0 0.5,0 0.799999,0c-0.1,0.3 -0.199999,0.5 -0.199999,0.8l0,0l0,0l0,0zm5.4,-6.400001h3.299999l0.5,5.8l3.200001,-5.8h3.4l-7.799999,13.8h-3.700001l2.4,-4.1l-1.299999,-9.7l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0zm-13.8,-2.8h-6.1l-2.7,12.5h3.6l0.9,-4.099999h2.5c2.5,0 4.5,-1.5 5,-4.1c0.7,-2.9 -1.4,-4.3 -3.2,-4.3l0,0l0,0l0,0zm-0.1,4.3c-0.2,0.9 -1.099999,1.7 -2,1.7h-1.7l0.7,-3.4h1.8c0.9,0 1.5,0.7 1.2,1.7z"
                            />
                          </g>
                        </g>
                        <g id="svg_81">
                          <g id="svg_82">
                            <path id="svg_83" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#999" d="m50.900002,5c-1.600002,0 -2.800003,0.4 -3.700001,0.6l-0.400002,2.4c0.5,-0.2 2,-0.6 3.200001,-0.7c1.200001,0 2,0.2 1.700001,1.3c-3.700001,0 -6.200001,0.799999 -6.700001,3.099999c-0.700001,4.1 3.799999,4 5.5,2.2l-0.200001,1h3.299999l1.400002,-6.5c0.700001,-2.8 -1.799999,-3.5 -4.099998,-3.4l0,0l0,0l0,0zm0.199997,6.6c-0.199997,0.9 -0.899998,1.2 -1.699997,1.299999c-0.700001,0 -1.400002,-0.599999 -0.900002,-1.4c0.400002,-0.6 1.400002,-0.8 2,-0.8c0.299999,0 0.5,0 0.799999,0c-0.099998,0.400001 -0.099998,0.6 -0.200001,0.900001zm6.800003,-9.2l0,0h3.399998l-2.700001,12.5h-3.299999l2.600002,-12.5l0,0zm-15.300003,0h-6.099998l-2.700001,12.4h3.5l0.900002,-4.1h2.5c2.5,0 4.5,-1.5 5.099998,-4.1c0.700001,-2.8 -1.399998,-4.2 -3.200001,-4.2zm-0.099998,4.3c-0.200001,0.9 -1.200001,1.7 -2.099998,1.7h-1.600002l0.700001,-3.4h1.799999c0.900002,0 1.400002,0.7 1.200001,1.7zm19.5,-2.7v-1.5h-0.5v-0.2h1.299999v0.2h-0.599998v1.5h-0.200001l0,0zm1,0v-1.7h0.299999l0.400002,1.2c0,0.1 0.099998,0.2 0.099998,0.2c0,-0.1 0,-0.1 0.100002,-0.3l0.400002,-1.2h0.299995v1.8h-0.199997v-1.4l-0.5,1.4h-0.200001l-0.5,-1.4v1.4h-0.200001l0,0z"
                            />
                          </g>
                          <g id="svg_84">
                            <path id="svg_85" class="paypal_svg" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#f5f5f5" d="m50.900002,4c-1.600002,0 -2.800003,0.4 -3.700001,0.6l-0.400002,2.4c0.5,-0.2 2,-0.6 3.200001,-0.7c1.200001,0 2,0.2 1.700001,1.3c-3.700001,0 -6.200001,0.8 -6.700001,3.1c-0.700001,4.1 3.799999,4 5.5,2.2l-0.200001,1h3.299999l1.400002,-6.5c0.700001,-2.8 -1.799999,-3.5 -4.099998,-3.4zm0.199997,6.6c-0.199997,0.9 -0.899998,1.2 -1.699997,1.299999c-0.700001,0 -1.400002,-0.599999 -0.900002,-1.4c0.400002,-0.6 1.400002,-0.8 2,-0.8c0.299999,0 0.5,0 0.799999,0c-0.099998,0.400001 -0.099998,0.6 -0.200001,0.900001l0,0zm6.800003,-9.2l0,0h3.399998l-2.700001,12.5h-3.299999l2.600002,-12.5l0,0zm-15.300003,0h-6.099998l-2.700001,12.4h3.5l0.900002,-4.1h2.5c2.5,0 4.5,-1.5 5.099998,-4.1c0.700001,-2.8 -1.399998,-4.2 -3.200001,-4.2zm-0.099998,4.3c-0.200001,0.9 -1.200001,1.7 -2.099998,1.7h-1.600002l0.700001,-3.4h1.799999c0.900002,0 1.400002,0.7 1.200001,1.7zm19.5,-2.7v-1.5h-0.5v-0.2h1.299999v0.2h-0.599998v1.5h-0.200001l0,0zm1,0v-1.7h0.299999l0.400002,1.2c0,0.1 0.099998,0.2 0.099998,0.2c0,-0.1 0,-0.1 0.100002,-0.3l0.400002,-1.2h0.299995v1.8h-0.199997v-1.4l-0.5,1.4h-0.200001l-0.5,-1.4v1.4h-0.200001l0,0z"
                            />
                          </g>
                        </g>
                      </svg>
                </div>
              </button>
              <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container force-width">
        <div class="col-md-12 tour">
          <div class="img-blue right"></div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi dignissim ante vitae auctor faucibus. Nunc est lorem, egestas a rutrum in, mollis nec nulla. Duis sit amet est vulputate, porta libero non, pellentesque elit. Aenean condimentum
            auctor posuere. Donec ut suscipit velit. Mauris sit amet aliquam augue. Mauris eleifend felis vitae consectetur varius. Donec eget mollis elit. Vestibulum nisl ante, lobortis a maximus tristique, bibendum sit amet enim. Nullam consectetur
            nec enim a sagittis. Nam eu finibus sapien. Aenean commodo turpis eu mauris bibendum, ut bibendum turpis ornare. Pellentesque tempus hendrerit sapien, vel finibus tellus placerat ut. Proin nisi nisi, vestibulum ut sodales eget, vehicula et
            mi. Vestibulum vel placerat tellus, at porttitor velit. Etiam et ornare urna, et hendrerit augue.</p>

          <p>Suspendisse congue facilisis augue et lacinia. Nulla convallis quam massa. Curabitur condimentum arcu at ante posuere pellentesque. Aliquam commodo, leo viverra sodales condimentum, ligula velit varius nunc, sit amet elementum justo tortor vitae
            arcu. Nam iaculis euismod malesuada. Quisque suscipit leo auctor, suscipit dui ac, viverra nisi. Donec sagittis tincidunt mi quis fermentum. Vivamus velit dolor, mollis in faucibus eget, tincidunt quis libero. Sed hendrerit, enim et venenatis
            faucibus, orci leo blandit sem, nec sagittis nunc sapien sit amet enim. Nam vel lorem in turpis imperdiet pharetra. Aenean ornare dictum neque, at faucibus enim faucibus et. Curabitur mauris nunc, commodo sed lectus sed, sodales bibendum nulla.
            Nullam non dolor accumsan, pulvinar massa quis, viverra dolor.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container force-width">
        <div class="col-md-12 tour">
          <div class="img-blue left"></div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi dignissim ante vitae auctor faucibus. Nunc est lorem, egestas a rutrum in, mollis nec nulla. Duis sit amet est vulputate, porta libero non, pellentesque elit. Aenean condimentum
            auctor posuere. Donec ut suscipit velit. Mauris sit amet aliquam augue. Mauris eleifend felis vitae consectetur varius. Donec eget mollis elit. Vestibulum nisl ante, lobortis a maximus tristique, bibendum sit amet enim. Nullam consectetur
            nec enim a sagittis. Nam eu finibus sapien. Aenean commodo turpis eu mauris bibendum, ut bibendum turpis ornare. Pellentesque tempus hendrerit sapien, vel finibus tellus placerat ut. Proin nisi nisi, vestibulum ut sodales eget, vehicula et
            mi. Vestibulum vel placerat tellus, at porttitor velit. Etiam et ornare urna, et hendrerit augue.</p>

          <p>Suspendisse congue facilisis augue et lacinia. Nulla convallis quam massa. Curabitur condimentum arcu at ante posuere pellentesque. Aliquam commodo, leo viverra sodales condimentum, ligula velit varius nunc, sit amet elementum justo tortor vitae
            arcu. Nam iaculis euismod malesuada. Quisque suscipit leo auctor, suscipit dui ac, viverra nisi. Donec sagittis tincidunt mi quis fermentum. Vivamus velit dolor, mollis in faucibus eget, tincidunt quis libero. Sed hendrerit, enim et venenatis
            faucibus, orci leo blandit sem, nec sagittis nunc sapien sit amet enim. Nam vel lorem in turpis imperdiet pharetra. Aenean ornare dictum neque, at faucibus enim faucibus et. Curabitur mauris nunc, commodo sed lectus sed, sodales bibendum nulla.
            Nullam non dolor accumsan, pulvinar massa quis, viverra dolor.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container force-width">
        <div class="col-md-12 tour">
          <div class="img-blue right"></div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi dignissim ante vitae auctor faucibus. Nunc est lorem, egestas a rutrum in, mollis nec nulla. Duis sit amet est vulputate, porta libero non, pellentesque elit. Aenean condimentum
            auctor posuere. Donec ut suscipit velit. Mauris sit amet aliquam augue. Mauris eleifend felis vitae consectetur varius. Donec eget mollis elit. Vestibulum nisl ante, lobortis a maximus tristique, bibendum sit amet enim. Nullam consectetur
            nec enim a sagittis. Nam eu finibus sapien. Aenean commodo turpis eu mauris bibendum, ut bibendum turpis ornare. Pellentesque tempus hendrerit sapien, vel finibus tellus placerat ut. Proin nisi nisi, vestibulum ut sodales eget, vehicula et
            mi. Vestibulum vel placerat tellus, at porttitor velit. Etiam et ornare urna, et hendrerit augue.</p>

          <p>Suspendisse congue facilisis augue et lacinia. Nulla convallis quam massa. Curabitur condimentum arcu at ante posuere pellentesque. Aliquam commodo, leo viverra sodales condimentum, ligula velit varius nunc, sit amet elementum justo tortor vitae
            arcu. Nam iaculis euismod malesuada. Quisque suscipit leo auctor, suscipit dui ac, viverra nisi. Donec sagittis tincidunt mi quis fermentum. Vivamus velit dolor, mollis in faucibus eget, tincidunt quis libero. Sed hendrerit, enim et venenatis
            faucibus, orci leo blandit sem, nec sagittis nunc sapien sit amet enim. Nam vel lorem in turpis imperdiet pharetra. Aenean ornare dictum neque, at faucibus enim faucibus et. Curabitur mauris nunc, commodo sed lectus sed, sodales bibendum nulla.
            Nullam non dolor accumsan, pulvinar massa quis, viverra dolor.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container force-width">
        <div class="col-md-12 center">
          <div class="row">
            <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
              <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
              <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="P22AKP9VXVBSC">
              <button name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg purchase" type="submit">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <b>Buy <i>with</i></b>
                      <svg id="svg_86" width="80px" height="25px" viewBox="0 0 66 19" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                        <g id="svg_88">
                          <g id="svg_89">
                            <path id="svg_90" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#999" d="m19,5c-1.5,0 -2.799999,0.4 -3.7,0.6l-0.3,2.4c0.4,-0.2 1.9,-0.6 3.1,-0.7c1.199999,0 1.9,0.2 1.699999,1.3c-3.599998,0 -6.099999,0.799999 -6.599999,3.099999c-0.7,4.1 3.7,4 5.400001,2.2l-0.200001,1h3.300001l1.4,-6.5c0.6,-2.8 -1.9,-3.5 -4.1,-3.4l0,0l0,0l0,0zm0.200001,6.6c-0.200001,0.9 -0.900002,1.2 -1.700001,1.299999c-0.700001,0 -1.299999,-0.599999 -0.9,-1.4c0.4,-0.6 1.4,-0.8 1.9,-0.8c0.299999,0 0.5,0 0.799999,0c0,0.400001 -0.099998,0.6 -0.099998,0.900001zm5.4,-6.400001h3.299999l0.5,5.8l3.200001,-5.8h3.4l-7.799999,13.8h-3.700001l2.4,-4.1l-1.299999,-9.7l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0zm-13.8,-2.8h-6.1l-2.7,12.5h3.6l0.9,-4.099999h2.5c2.5,0 4.5,-1.5 5,-4.1c0.7,-2.9 -1.4,-4.3 -3.2,-4.3l0,0l0,0l0,0zm-0.1,4.3c-0.2,0.9 -1.099999,1.7 -2,1.7h-1.7l0.7,-3.4h1.8c0.9,0 1.5,0.7 1.2,1.7z"
                            />
                          </g>
                          <g id="svg_91">
                            <path id="svg_92" class="paypal_svg" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#f5f5f5" d="m19,4c-1.5,0 -2.799999,0.4 -3.7,0.6l-0.3,2.4c0.4,-0.2 1.9,-0.6 3.1,-0.7c1.199999,0 1.9,0.2 1.699999,1.3c-3.599998,0 -6.099999,0.8 -6.599999,3.1c-0.7,4.1 3.7,4 5.400001,2.2l-0.200001,1h3.300001l1.4,-6.5c0.6,-2.8 -1.9,-3.5 -4.1,-3.4l0,0l0,0l0,0zm0.200001,6.6c-0.200001,0.9 -0.900002,1.2 -1.700001,1.299999c-0.700001,0 -1.299999,-0.599999 -0.9,-1.4c0.4,-0.6 1.4,-0.7 2,-0.7c0.299999,0 0.5,0 0.799999,0c-0.1,0.3 -0.199999,0.5 -0.199999,0.8l0,0l0,0l0,0zm5.4,-6.400001h3.299999l0.5,5.8l3.200001,-5.8h3.4l-7.799999,13.8h-3.700001l2.4,-4.1l-1.299999,-9.7l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0zm-13.8,-2.8h-6.1l-2.7,12.5h3.6l0.9,-4.099999h2.5c2.5,0 4.5,-1.5 5,-4.1c0.7,-2.9 -1.4,-4.3 -3.2,-4.3l0,0l0,0l0,0zm-0.1,4.3c-0.2,0.9 -1.099999,1.7 -2,1.7h-1.7l0.7,-3.4h1.8c0.9,0 1.5,0.7 1.2,1.7z"
                            />
                          </g>
                        </g>
                        <g id="svg_93">
                          <g id="svg_94">
                            <path id="svg_95" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#999" d="m50.900002,5c-1.600002,0 -2.800003,0.4 -3.700001,0.6l-0.400002,2.4c0.5,-0.2 2,-0.6 3.200001,-0.7c1.200001,0 2,0.2 1.700001,1.3c-3.700001,0 -6.200001,0.799999 -6.700001,3.099999c-0.700001,4.1 3.799999,4 5.5,2.2l-0.200001,1h3.299999l1.400002,-6.5c0.700001,-2.8 -1.799999,-3.5 -4.099998,-3.4l0,0l0,0l0,0zm0.199997,6.6c-0.199997,0.9 -0.899998,1.2 -1.699997,1.299999c-0.700001,0 -1.400002,-0.599999 -0.900002,-1.4c0.400002,-0.6 1.400002,-0.8 2,-0.8c0.299999,0 0.5,0 0.799999,0c-0.099998,0.400001 -0.099998,0.6 -0.200001,0.900001zm6.800003,-9.2l0,0h3.399998l-2.700001,12.5h-3.299999l2.600002,-12.5l0,0zm-15.300003,0h-6.099998l-2.700001,12.4h3.5l0.900002,-4.1h2.5c2.5,0 4.5,-1.5 5.099998,-4.1c0.700001,-2.8 -1.399998,-4.2 -3.200001,-4.2zm-0.099998,4.3c-0.200001,0.9 -1.200001,1.7 -2.099998,1.7h-1.600002l0.700001,-3.4h1.799999c0.900002,0 1.400002,0.7 1.200001,1.7zm19.5,-2.7v-1.5h-0.5v-0.2h1.299999v0.2h-0.599998v1.5h-0.200001l0,0zm1,0v-1.7h0.299999l0.400002,1.2c0,0.1 0.099998,0.2 0.099998,0.2c0,-0.1 0,-0.1 0.100002,-0.3l0.400002,-1.2h0.299995v1.8h-0.199997v-1.4l-0.5,1.4h-0.200001l-0.5,-1.4v1.4h-0.200001l0,0z"
                            />
                          </g>
                          <g id="svg_96">
                            <path id="svg_97" class="paypal_svg" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#f5f5f5" d="m50.900002,4c-1.600002,0 -2.800003,0.4 -3.700001,0.6l-0.400002,2.4c0.5,-0.2 2,-0.6 3.200001,-0.7c1.200001,0 2,0.2 1.700001,1.3c-3.700001,0 -6.200001,0.8 -6.700001,3.1c-0.700001,4.1 3.799999,4 5.5,2.2l-0.200001,1h3.299999l1.400002,-6.5c0.700001,-2.8 -1.799999,-3.5 -4.099998,-3.4zm0.199997,6.6c-0.199997,0.9 -0.899998,1.2 -1.699997,1.299999c-0.700001,0 -1.400002,-0.599999 -0.900002,-1.4c0.400002,-0.6 1.400002,-0.8 2,-0.8c0.299999,0 0.5,0 0.799999,0c-0.099998,0.400001 -0.099998,0.6 -0.200001,0.900001l0,0zm6.800003,-9.2l0,0h3.399998l-2.700001,12.5h-3.299999l2.600002,-12.5l0,0zm-15.300003,0h-6.099998l-2.700001,12.4h3.5l0.900002,-4.1h2.5c2.5,0 4.5,-1.5 5.099998,-4.1c0.700001,-2.8 -1.399998,-4.2 -3.200001,-4.2zm-0.099998,4.3c-0.200001,0.9 -1.200001,1.7 -2.099998,1.7h-1.600002l0.700001,-3.4h1.799999c0.900002,0 1.400002,0.7 1.200001,1.7zm19.5,-2.7v-1.5h-0.5v-0.2h1.299999v0.2h-0.599998v1.5h-0.200001l0,0zm1,0v-1.7h0.299999l0.400002,1.2c0,0.1 0.099998,0.2 0.099998,0.2c0,-0.1 0,-0.1 0.100002,-0.3l0.400002,-1.2h0.299995v1.8h-0.199997v-1.4l-0.5,1.4h-0.200001l-0.5,-1.4v1.4h-0.200001l0,0z"
                            />
                          </g>
                        </g>
                      </svg>
                </div>
              </button>
              <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```